# Changing html text with button click

Tags: javascript, html, function, events, button

I got into js few days ago. I started playing with new stuff functions and events but I got stuck here

```js
var str = ["A", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

function Generate() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var countStr = 0;
  text.innerHTML = str[countStr];
  countStr += 1;

}
```

```html
<div id="quote">
  <p id="text">I'm a paragraph</p>
</div>
<button id="butt" onclick="Generate()">Generate</button>
```

when I click the button the text changes to str[0] but when I click again it doesn't change;  can you tell me why ?

Comment: `countStr` is set to 0 every time you call the `Generate` function...

Comment: Move the countStr outside the function and make sure your countStr does not exceed str.length

Comment: @Closer - this contains the code necessary to show the problem

Comment: @Zied, what about accepting answer in order to help other people ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behaviour exists because everytime you `click` button, `countStr` variable  will be 0. You need to declare it outside the function.

```js
var str = ["A", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var countStr = 0;
function Generate() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text");  
  text.innerHTML = str[countStr];
  countStr += 1;

}
```

```html
<div id="quote">
  <p id="text">Im a paragraph</p>
</div>
<button id="butt" onclick="Generate()">Generate</button>
```

Another method is to use a `closure` function.

Read more about `closures`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

```js
var str = ["A", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var generate=(function() {  
  var countStr = 0;
  return function(){
     text.innerHTML = str[countStr];
     return countStr+=1;
  }

})();
```

```html
<div id="quote">
  <p id="text">I'm a paragraph</p>
</div>
<button id="butt" onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Because your `countStr` variable is local scoped. It means, when you call the function `Generate()`, it everytime creates a new `countStr` variable and set's it's value to `0` and for improvement put the `document.getElementById("text")` also outside the function.

Put it outside of the function.

```js
var str = ["A", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var countStr = 0;

var text = document.getElementById("text");

function Generate() {      
  text.innerHTML = str[countStr];
  countStr += 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="quote">
  <p id="text">Im a paragraph</p>
</div>
<button id="butt" onclick="Generate()">Generate</button>
```

Comment: Probably someone voting before you finished your answer

Comment: sorry to bother you but i got another question :c 
is it possible to not use "onclick="generate()" in html and instead i use 
button.addEvenetListener("click",Generate(){}; ? does it work the same as the first one ?

Comment: `onclick="generate()` will work in every browser, but `addEvenetListener` will not work in Internet Explorer. For IE you need to use `attachEvent`. But in global, they are the same, but the best practice is to use code attachment as the second case.